Format text based on text style using React js
I need to format text based on provided text specific style using react js. e.g:
Here i have observed one thing like, if i pass text with some variable e.g:
const text = "\\nBubble\\nAir\\nSKY";
 <myComponent variableText={text} />

Then inside my component when i inspect the passed data it shows like below:
"Bubble
 Air
 SKY"

If i get data like in this type of format, It is working fine for me. But when i direct pass the string text in my component like below:
<myComponent text="\nBubble\nAir\nSky" />

So after inspect in the component passed text it shows same like string.
e.g: "\nBubble\nAir\SKY";
How do we first get the string value as text in React js?
Need help



const MyComponent = ({ text }) => {
  // Replace \n with <br> tags for HTML rendering
  const formattedText = text.replace(/\\n/g, '<br>');

  return (
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: formattedText }} />
  );
};



Try to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML

This code works fine for me. In that case first it replace the \n with  then i split  and do my code stuff to achieve my requirement. I will mark it as answer.

as i understood your component like this :
 const MyComponent = ({ text }) => {
      return (
        <div>
          {text.split('\n').map((item, index) => (
            <span key={index}>
              {item}
              <br />
            </span>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    };

You can modify your component with your specific splitter do you want or you can use just an method like this :
const formatText = (text) => {
  return text.split('\n').map((item, key) => (
    <span key={key}>
      {item}
      <br />
    </span>
  ));
};


The above code will only work if i get the string as a text format, If it is in string format, It does not find '\n' there.

If use this as Direct String it will be use as regular String , if you want to break the string you can use a formatter
const formattedText = text.split('\\n').join('\n');

now in your Component you can use as you wish
    <div style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-line' }}>
      {formattedText}
    </div>

then when you use it you can pass the string
const text = "\nBubble\nAir\nSky";

Please consider my first string text, There is single slash 'n' '\n' not double slash.

yes that's right I just gave you example , then you can directly use this style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-line' }}
